# how to override framwork class in magento2

Tags: magento2, search

I am trying to override `magento/framework/Search/Search` class for which I have used in  **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="magento\framework\Search\Search" type="vendorname\moudelname\Search\Search"/> 
</config>
```

I am not able to override the Magento class.

Comment: Hello, please add your **di.xml** file code to have a look at your code.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="magento\framework\Search\Search" type="vendor\moudlename\Search\Search"/> 
</config>

Comment: but it dose  not work

Comment: Have you made a separate module and are you sure that you are adding di.xml from the right area

Comment: it would be great if you can manage to upload your complete code base for your custom module?

Comment: yes i add it in etc/di.xml

Comment: I think Ansar's answer will help resolve the issue. Give it a try and update your **di.xml** with provided code.

Comment: I agree with Jaimin as in your di.xml there are some typo mistake of small and capital which is crucial for Magento 2 to find out correct path

Comment: ok what i am trying to do is to custom this function search(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)  
i put the same code which place in  oreganal file and add my custom  issue put it dose not read it

Answer (score 1):

now I am trying to override Search.php which was placed in Magento\framework\Search\Search bellow my code, I am trying to let Magento search in both store views, I have done it in the original search.php file it works fine but when I try to override using preference but it doesn't work that is why now am using the plugin.
this is the di.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\Search\Search">
    <plugin name="ProSearch" type="vendor\Search\Plugin\Search\Search" />
</type>
```

and this the plugin function

```
   public function aroundSearch(\Magento\Framework\Search\Search $subject,\Closure $proceed ,\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
 {
    
    
                
                $this->requestBuilder->setRequestName($searchCriteria->getRequestName());
                
                $storeIds=[1,2];
                foreach ($storeIds as $storeid) {   
                $scope=$storeid ;                   
                $this->requestBuilder->bindDimension('scope', $scope);
                                                }
               // $scope = $this->scopeResolver->getScope()->getId();
               // $this->requestBuilder->bindDimension('scope', $scope);

                foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $filterGroup) {
                    foreach ($filterGroup->getFilters() as $filter) {
                        $this->addFieldToFilter($filter->getField(), $filter->getValue());
                    }
                }

                $this->requestBuilder->setFrom($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage() * $searchCriteria->getPageSize());
                $this->requestBuilder->setSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());
                $request = $this->requestBuilder->create();
                $searchResponse = $this->searchEngine->search($request);

                return $proceed();      
                        

        
 }
```

Comment: i did the same but it dosnt work ,

Comment: any way to overide it with new plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

We can override using preference.

- Create di.xml
- Create class php file

  ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader" type="NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader" />
  ```
- In the given path put your fle `NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader`